# Android 5.0.2 web view password field does not post password actually typed

Tags: android, webview, socketscan

I have a simple web page that has a username and password field. If I fill out the username and password field and use the "GO" button on the keyboard the data posts correctly to the server.

But if I don't use the keyboard's GO button and click the "Login" button the the web page the password is sent as ********e for example. It seems like Android `WebView` has some sort of bug.

I figured this out by outputting the RAW post data from server.

SEE:

[image: Screenshot]

This doesn't happen in Chrome on Android or iOS. Just my Android `WebView`. There is not any javascript on the web page that would cause this. I am just typing a password in.

This is on Android 5.0.2 AND 5.1. It does NOT happen on Android 4.3 in the same app using `WebView`.

Here is how I start my StoreWebActivity:

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(StoreUrlActivity.this, StoreWebActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("storeUrl", savedStoreUrl);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Here is what I do in `onCreate` for activity:

```
this.webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);     
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");

...
webView.loadUrl(storeUrl);
```

This simple form has issue for testing (http://chrismuench.com/android_password_bug.php)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['password']))
{
    var_dump($_POST['password']);
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is a bare bones android app with a web view using android studio that shows the bug

https://github.com/blasto333/AndroidWebViewBug

Comment: I have tested your sample application in Android 5.1 version and it is working fine. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/858web06723gzay/Screenshot%202015-12-16%2010.59.54.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oa68kk86fbuh62g/Screenshot%202015-12-16%2011.00.16.png?dl=0

It would help if you can post the device/emulator information.

Comment: Thanks! When you said you tried a different device I tried to figure out what was different. When I use the SocketScan keyboard/bluetooth scanner this is when it happens. If I switch the keyboard back to the regular keyboard it works as expected. I would never think that this would cause issue. I will let the company know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for providing such complete information about this issue. I was able to reproduce it on both Android 5.1 and 6.0. It appears to have been caused by predictions being enabled for password fields in web forms. The **fix has been released in v10.2.1**, which is available on the Google Play Store.

Google added a separate input type for web form passwords in SDK 11, so I'm surprised we are only seeing this issue now. Something must have changed in Chromium recently, because reverting to Android System WebView version 44.0.2403.117 or earlier seems to fix the issue too.

Comment: Thanks so much. You guys are the most responsive company I have ever met.

Comment: confirmed that version 10.2.1 fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to SocketScan bluetooth barcode scanner that creates a keyboard. When this keyboard is in use this issues happens in WebViews. I am not sure if this happens with other custom keyboards at this time.